# Not able to get datetime properly data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have this following in a table

```
--2,4,1| 2016-02-21 10:22:00 | 2016-02-21 12:22:00 --
```

namely `id's(varchar)`, `fromtime(datetime)` and `totime(datetime)`

I want this id set to be returned when using

```
Select ids 
from Schedule 
where fromtime between '2016/02/21 10:00:00' and '2016/02/21 12:00:00' 
      and totime between '2016/02/21 10:00:00' and '2016/02/21 12:00:00'
```

But it returns empty set, on the other hand if use this query

```
Select Participantsids 
from Schedule 
where fromtime between '2016/02/21 10:00:00' and '2016/02/21 13:00:00' 
      and totime between '2016/02/21 10:00:00' and '2016/02/21 13:00:00';
```

It returns the desired results.That is I need to cover the `fromtime` and `totime` completely to get my results.Is there a way to get results when my  time is like 10:30 - 12:00 ?

Comment: database datetime structure is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` you send value this format . you remove `slash` to `hi-pen` .its work fine

Comment: @VadivelS- No still returns empty set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for *overlapping* intervals use these predicates:

```
SELECT ids 
FROM Schedule 
WHERE fromtime <= '2016-02-21 12:00:00' AND totime >= '2016-02-21 10:00:00'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a377e/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select Participantsids 
from Schedule 
where fromtime between '2016-02-21 10:00:00' and '2016-02-21 13:00:00' 
and totime between '2016-02-21 10:00:00' and '2016-02-21 13:00:00';
```